# how to use carousel in Lightning web component see below code + need some sample example how to implement in lwc

Tags: salesforce-lightning, lwc

how to use carousel in Lightning web component.need some sample example how to implement in lwc.

Comment: Need idea how to use the below js in html.

https://react.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/carousel/

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/carousel/

Answer (score 0):

this is quite simple similar to other LWC Components, find the below sample code:

HTML:

```html
<lightning-carousel-image 
    key={myArray.Id} 
    src={myArray.imageURL} 
    href={myArray.pageURL}
>
</lightning-carousel-image>
```

JS:

```js
export default class MyEvents extends LightningElement {
  @track myArray = [];
  connectedCallback() {
    yourApexMethod()
      .then(result => {
        if (result) {
          this.myArray = result;
          }
        }
      }).catch(error => {

      })
  }
```

**You must need to whitelist your image URL by adding it to CSP trusted sites and Remote Site Settings**

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official documentation on lightning-carousel-image

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-carousel-image/documentation

```
<lightning-carousel>
    <lightning-carousel-image
        src="path/to/carousel-01.jpg"
        header="First card"
        description="First card description"
        alternative-text="This is a card"
        href="https://www.example.com">
    </lightning-carousel-image>

    <lightning-carousel-image
        src="path/to/carousel-02.jpg"
        header="Second card"
        description="Second card description"
        alternative-text="This is a card"
        href="https://www.example.com">
    </lightning-carousel-image>
</lightning-carousel>
```

Also, do the whitelisting as well :)